# Android CheckBoxPreference and global variables

Tags: android, global-variables, checkboxpreference

I am developing an android browser and i have a `CheckBoxPreference` that i want it to set a global `int` variable to 1 if checked and to 0 if unchecked
here's my code:
 xml/prefs

```
 <CheckBoxPreference
                    android:key="enable_lock"
                    android:summary="Check to lock bSurfer with a password"
                    android:title="Enable app lock" android:defaultValue="true"/>
```

i have a `Global` class that has the following setter and getter:

```
public static int ENABLE_APP_LOCK;
public static int getENABLE_APP_LOCK() {
    return ENABLE_APP_LOCK;
}

public static void setENABLE_APP_LOCK(int eNABLE_APP_LOCK) {
    ENABLE_APP_LOCK = eNABLE_APP_LOCK;
}
```

in my MainActivity i check the value of the checkbox as follows

```
boolean appLock = getPrefs.getBoolean("enable_lock", false);
if (appLock == true) {
            Global.setENABLE_APP_LOCK(1);
        } else if(appLock==false) {
            Global.setENABLE_APP_LOCK(0);
        }
```

i also have a splash screen that waits for 3 seconds and checks the Global var `int ENABLE_APP_LOCK` if `1` start an activity if `0` start another activity

```
if(Global.ENABLE_APP_LOCK==1){
                Intent openAC = new Intent("com.bisho.bsurfer.PASSCHECK");
                startActivity(openAC);
                }else if(Global.ENABLE_APP_LOCK==0){
                    Intent in2 = new Intent("com.bisho.bsurfer.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(in2);
                }
```

The problem iam having is whether i check the CheckBox or not , it always start the second activity, can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your splash screen is started before you check the value of the checkbox i think.

Comment: No..i already set the checkbox to true which should start the first activity as it first start up...in the `if(Global.ENABLE_APP_LOCK==1)`

Comment: You set the checkbox to true and then invoke a splash sceen? What kind of scenario is that? I would think: You start your app while the CheckBoxPreference is true. And then you start an activity. Better show more code so we can inspect the sequence as that is unclear now. I referred to the 'check' in `in my MainActivity i check the value of the checkbox as follows`.

Comment: Dude...it is a checkbox preference, if it is checked that means it will change the value of the global var to 1 which will start the first activity next time the app is launched ..

Comment: So about the sequence: the global will be set to 1. Then you close your app. Then you restart and the global is .. 0. Strange? No. Ofcourse it is 0 then.